# Implementation of a buffer with an underlying FILE pointer

Tags: performance, c, io, library

I am writing a library that will be used as input for any application the library is embedded, let's say, an interactive shell or to read from a `FILE *`.

I need to know which improvements could be made to the snippets below, if a test snippet with a `main()` function is needed, please let me know.

**reader.h**:

```
#if !defined(READER_H)
#define READER_H

#include <stdint.h> /* For uint32_t */
#include <stdio.h>  /* For FILE *   */

/**
 * Reader struct, must be allocated on stack.
 */
typedef struct _reader {
  FILE    *ifp; /* File input buffer.    */
  char    *buf; /* Raw line buffer.      */
  uint32_t len; /* Line length.          */
  uint32_t mul; /* Raw line multiplier.  */
  uint32_t cur; /* Current char on line. */
} reader_t;

/**
 * Opens a new reader, use NULL as @_path to open stdin.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int r_open(reader_t *_reader, const char *_path);

/**
 * Opens a new reader without a file stream.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int r_open_str(reader_t *_reader, const char *_str);

/**
 * Releases memory on internal components and closes the internal file.
 */
void r_close(reader_t *_reader);

/**
 * Reads a line from the current @_reader instance and prints a prompt.
 * Prompt will not be printed to stdout if the file is not stdin.
 * use the @_prompt when running in interactive mode.
 * Returns the length of the string read in the last pass.
 */
uint32_t r_read(reader_t *_reader, const char *_prompt);

/**
 * Peeks a character without changing the current position index on reader.
 * Returns 0 if there are no characters left on current line.
 */
int r_peekc(reader_t *_reader);

/**
 * Advances a position in the reader and returns the same as r_peekc.
 */
int r_nextc(reader_t *_reader);

/**
 * Use this function when iterating the line, returns whether the marker
 * is at end of line.
 */
int r_at_eol(reader_t *_reader);

/**
 * Use this function when you want to know if both markers are past end.
 * This function should be only used when reading content from a file that is
 * not stdin, use at your own risk.
 */
int r_at_eof(reader_t *_reader);

#endif /* READER_H */
```

**reader.c**:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <reader.h>

/* Open a new reader. */
int r_open(reader_t *_reader, const char *_path) {
  if (!_reader)
    return 1;

  _reader->ifp = (_path)? fopen(_path, "rb"): stdin;
  if (!_reader->ifp)  /* Stop now if not opened. */
    return 1;

  _reader->len = 0;
  _reader->mul = 0; /* Mul is used on this context. */
  _reader->cur = 0;
  _reader->buf = NULL;

  return 0;
}

/* Let's open a simple string. */
int r_open_str(reader_t *_reader, const char *_str) {
  if (!_reader || !_str)
    return 1;

  _reader->ifp = NULL; /* Set ifp to null explicitly. */
  _reader->cur = 0; /* mul is not used on this context. */
  _reader->len = strlen(_str);
  _reader->buf = calloc(_reader->len, 1);
  memcpy(_reader->buf, _str, _reader->len); /* Copy the content. */

  return 0;
}

/* Just close the reader and release its memory. */
void r_close(reader_t *_reader) {
  if (_reader) {
    free(_reader->buf), _reader->buf = NULL;
    if (_reader->ifp && (_reader->ifp != stdin))
      fclose(_reader->ifp);
  }
}

/* Peeks the current character. */
int r_peekc(reader_t *_reader) {
  return (!r_at_eol(_reader))? _reader->buf[_reader->cur]: 0;
}

/* Advance a position on reader. */
int r_nextc(reader_t *_reader) {
  if (_reader)
    ++(_reader->cur); /* Advance no matter what. */
  return r_peekc(_reader); /* It's up to you receive whatever. */
}

/* Checks whether we're at eol on current line. */
int r_at_eol(reader_t *_reader) {
  return (_reader && (_reader->cur >= _reader->len));
}

/* Are we really at eof? MUST use when reading from a file. */
int r_at_eof(reader_t *_reader) {
  /* We cannot and shouldn't get the EOF status of stdin... */
  return (_reader && _reader->ifp) && (_reader->ifp != stdin)
      && feof(_reader->ifp) && (_reader->cur >= _reader->len);
}


#define MAX_BUF_MULT (120)  /* Max buffer multiplier. */
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE (1024) /* The max buffer size.   */
/* Let's read a line with a fancy prompt ;)  *
 * This function overwrites the same buffer. */
uint32_t r_read(reader_t *_reader, const char *_prompt) {
  if (_reader) {
    /* Cut it out if we don't have a file. */
    if (!_reader->ifp || feof(_reader->ifp))
      return 0;
    else if ((_reader->ifp == stdin) && _prompt) /* Print prompt if exists. */
      printf("%s", _prompt);
    /* Reset the buffer if past the max size. */
    if (_reader->mul >= MAX_BUF_SIZE)
      free(_reader->buf), _reader->buf = NULL, _reader->mul = 0;

    _reader->cur = 0; /* Reset the current position.          */
    _reader->len = 0; /* We will receive a new string, right? */
    int c = 0;        /* Store the current character (temp).  */
    while (1) {
      c = fgetc(_reader->ifp);
      if (c == '\n' || c == EOF)
         break;

      /* If we ran out of space for characters. */
      if (_reader->len >= _reader->mul) {
        char *tmp = realloc(_reader->buf, _reader->mul + MAX_BUF_MULT);
        if (!tmp) /* If we could not allocate, just break and return. */
          break;
        _reader->buf = tmp; /* Set the buffer back. */
        _reader->mul += MAX_BUF_MULT;
      }
      _reader->buf[_reader->len] = c; /* Assign the character back. */
      ++(_reader->len);
    }
    /* Do it again, if we're at EOF, 0 will be returned ;) */
    if (!_reader->len)
      return r_read(_reader, _prompt);
    _reader->buf[_reader->len] = 0;
  }

  return (_reader)? _reader->len: 0; /* Return the same length. */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wow, awesome peace of code!**

It is properly formatted and well commented.

Some things I noticed in no particular order:

- missed `NULL` check after `calloc(_reader->len, 1)`
- `_t` is POSIX thing, you *may* decide to stick to CamelCase or add some type prefix
- use of `_` before argument name looks rather unusuall, but I guess it is okay

Apart from that your code is rather solid.

Comment: ¡Nice eye for #1! For #2, I'm used to add an `_t` at the end of the `typedef` but I think there is not any problem with the prefix, For #3 that's an old habit :P ¡Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @NaCl, `#if !defined(READER_H)` vs `#ifndef READER_H`

Comment: Do they behave differently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617712/difference-between-ifndef-and-if-defined-in-c
The latter it my personal favorite, is aligns nicely with next line `#define READER_H`